# How to join 3 tables using codeigniter without any null values in table?

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

**My Query is**

```
$this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('private_messages');         
    $this->db->join('admin', 'admin.admin_id = private_messages.from_id', 'left');                
    $this->db->join('user', 'user.user_id = private_messages.from_id', 'left');
    $this->db->where('private_messages.hash_id',$id);
    $this->db->order_by('private_messages.time_sent','asc');
    $query=$this->db->get();        
    return $query->result_array();
```

**Output was:**

```
form_id | Username | Username
21      |Praveen   |NULL
21      |Praveen   |NULL
3       |NULL      |admin
3       |NULL      |admin
```

So please help remove all null and put username in single column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get nulls from `admin` and `user` tables because you're using a LEFT JOIN.

> If there is no matching row for the right table in the ON or USING part in a LEFT JOIN, a row with all columns set to NULL is used for the right table. You can use this fact to find rows in a table that have no counterpart in another table.

So, for example this line:

```
$this->db->join('admin', 'admin.admin_id = private_messages.from_id', 'left');
```

should be this:

```
$this->db->join('admin', 'admin.admin_id = private_messages.from_id');
```

---

Read more info about CodeIgniter's Active Records and joins here: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

And more info about MySQL joins here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

---

UPDATE

> "i want username in single column and shows username match to the message_id. Is possible?"

Yes, that would be something like this:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('private_messages');         
$this->db->join('user', 'user.user_id = private_messages.from_id');
$this->db->where('private_messages.hash_id',$id);
$this->db->order_by('private_messages.time_sent','asc');
$query=$this->db->get();        
return $query->result_array();
```

Comment: Thanku..But when i remove left it only shows admin details..!

Comment: If you remove left, it will show rows that have matching values for each table - so if you remove it for admins, it will only show rows that have a proper admin id for each message, if you remove it for users, it will only show rows with an existing user from the message id, if you remove for both admins and users, it will only show the rows that have BOTH admin and user ids. Which one do you need?

Comment: i want username in single column and shows username match to the message_id. Is possible??

Comment: Ya.. It's simple join query for only join with user table..i want to use 3 table..merge the user and admin username in single column

Comment: Aren't those usernames the same? Aren't the admins also the users?

Comment: But those are different IDs, how can you join them?

Comment: No username only same..but different table User table and Admin Table.

Comment: So it's not possible??

Comment: Anything's possible, but I'm not sure I understand what you want. Can you accomplish it by doing what I did in the updated answer and then union it with the same query that will do the join with the admin table?

Comment: I already mentioned i want to join 3 tables..when i join 2 tables there are no NULL values return..then i join three table i got NULL values like above i mentioned.so when i fetch the row username in message box its show only sender(user) username and doesn't show receiver(admin) username that's the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure you're doing the right thing with the database structure. What will happen if I'm a user with id, for example, 3; and you're an admin also with id 3? And if you do a union with no LEFT joins, you'd get no NULL values, only the combined results of user and admin tables having message IDs.

Comment: No..it's working perfectly..sending and receiving message good.. Hmm Ok i'll send screenshot link..

Comment: Here is the screenshot: [link](http://jpcreation.site50.net/stackoverflow/Capture.PNG)

Comment: I understand that, but how would you know that user ID3 and admin ID3 are different? What if user ID3 is "Shomz" (me) and admin ID3 is "Praveen", who gets the message - you or me? Because both you and me would get selected with that query.

Comment: No bro..id is different. I mentioned from_id means combined both user & admin id like admin id is 3 and user id is 21..there are three tables table 1->message,table 2->user,table 3->admin but column 'username' is same in admin & user.

Comment: Then you definitely have a bad table design. And your queries are wrong because you're using `id` to fetch data, yet the user and admin data is only related by `username`. You can stlil make it work using UNION, as I already said a few times, but I *guarantee* you'll start getting weird results once you get more users because you have duplicated users (regular ones and admins) with different primary keys. Sorry, I can't tell anything else, you have the solution (union) if you still wish to proceed this way...

Comment: You're welcome. Oh, btw. Active Records don't support UNION if I'm not mistaken, so you'd have to rewrite your code to use `$this->db->query`... and then do user query union admin query. That will get you the combined user/admin data based on from_id.